# ES6 class method returning this can't be called by stderr.on('data')

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Learning the specifics of ES6 / NodeJS / JavaScript classes. I've created a log script which I'm passing to child_process. First, here's the logging class `./bin/log`:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs')
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp')

module.exports = class Log {

  constructor(logDir='./', name='log.log.txt', callback = ()=>{}) {
    let dt = new Date()
    this.dir = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (Number(dt.getMonth()) + 1).toString()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2)
    this.filename = `${logDir}${this.dir}/${name}.${Math.round(Date.now())}.log.txt`
    mkdirp(logDir + this.dir + '/', (err) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      fs.appendFile(this.filename, `${process.argv.join(' ')}\n${dt.toString()}\n`, (e) => {
        if (e) return callback(e);
        callback(null);
      })
    })
  }

  log(msg='') {
    fs.appendFileSync(this.filename, msg.toString() + '\n');
    return this;
  }

  err(e='') {
    fs.appendFileSync(this.filename, `Error!: ${e.toString()}\n`);
    return this;
  }

}
```

So this works in my main file:

```
const child_process = require('child_process')
const Log = require('./bin/log')
let log = new Log('./logs/', 'KPI-Update', function(e) {
  if (e) return console.error(e);
  let child = child_process.spawn("Rscript", ["./bin/main.R"])
  child.stderr.on("data",(d)=>{log.err(d)})
  child.stdout.on("data",(d)=>{log.log(d)})
  child.stdout.on("close",(d)=>{log.log(d)})
})
```

But this only works on the first call (on the second call, the context for `this` has been changed to the child_process socket. What am I not understanding here?

```
child.stderr.on("data",log.err)
child.stdout.on("data",log.log)
child.stdout.on("close",log.log)
```

Comment: That second one is passing _just_ the functions, with no attachment to `log`, which is why it will fail. You'd need to do `, log.err.bind(log)`

Comment: Where would I log.err.bind(log)? Inside the class constructor?

Comment: FYI this could very well be the most commonly asked JS question, it's just hard to find a nice thing to dedup against since everything uses functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
child.stderr.on("data",log.err)
```

is just like

```
let err = log.err;
child.stderr.on("data", err)
```

meaning you are pulling a function off the class and passing it as a callback, but when you pull a function off like that, it will no longer pass the correct `this` value to the `err` function when called. When you do

```
(d) => log.err(d)
```

you are creating a new function that will call `log.err` properly.

The alternative is that you could do

```
child.stderr.on("data", log.err.bind(this))
```

or in your class constructor you could do

```
this.log = this.log.bind(this);
this.err = this.err.bind(this);
```

to override the functions from the class prototype with instance variables that have the correct `this` force-set, so then doing

```
child.stderr.on("data", log.err)
```

would work fine.

I'd recommend reading up on how `this` works, since that seems to be a major tripping point for this question.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a best practice for what I'm doing? Or is it really just that I have to decide which way I prefer?